# mvprintw function

Tags: printing

I am trying to create the game called Missile Command (was played on atari back in the day). So far I have gotten the movement on mu cursor on a window.

I am using mvprintw() but I am pretty sure the problem is somewhere with 'y' (the lines).

Comment: "cannot think of a way to create an explosion using ASCII art on click" - when you say "on click", you mean, on a key press presumably? Also, it's unclear what doesn't work from your question.

Comment: I am afraid I don't use `ncurses` so I don't know in what way `mvprintw` behaves differently compared to `mvwaddch`. For start, it seems a bit strange that `x` in `draw_explosion` is actually far away from the center of the explosion. There is no bounds checking there so I'd prefer to do this properly (and perhaps you don't need the spaces and `mvprintw`, two `for` loops calling `display_movement` would work fine for `(y-2)..(y+2)`, `(x-2)..(x+2)`. I'd start with a breakpoint in `draw_explosion` and stepping through to see how the screen is being updated, and if you even get `p` from `wgetch`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the example program `firework.c`, versions of which come with both ncurses and PDCurses, that mainly does exactly this. The core function there, `explode()`, is similar to your `draw_explosion()`, except that it draws the explosion in stages, with pauses between them.

https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/demos/firework.c

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the explosion isn't drawn in the window.

You should change the `draw_explosion` to take arguments: `WINDOW *win, int y, int x`, and also change `mvprintw` to `mvwprintw` in that function.

Finally don't forget to update how you call that function to: `draw_explosion(mainWin, y, x);`